# Difference between the consecutive terms of an increasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(u_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a strictely incerasing sequennce such that,  $(u_n)$  converege and $u_n>0$

do we have always that
$$u_{n+1}-u_{n}>u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}$$

for $ n$  large enough.

Comment: What are your attempts on showing this inequality?

Comment: Draw some pictures of the points $(n, u_n)$ in the plane. Your condition means that $u_{n+1}$ is “above” the line joining $u_n$ and $u_{n+2}$ (that would be called “concave” for a function). Then think how the sequence can be modified to violate your condition and still be increasing and convergent.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR ,If I understand your idea. The sequence should be constant for $n $ large enough. But by assumption the sequence is strictly increasing !

Comment: The converse of your statement is that we have $$u_{n+1}-u_{n}\leq u_{n+2}-u_{n+1}$$ for *every* $n$. Can you find a contradiction?

Comment: Counterexample: $1, 1.03, 1.11, 1.1103, 1.111, 1.11103, 1.1111, \ldots$

Comment: Thanks @macton . I don't find  the contradiction

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird. You are asking whether there *exists* a $n$ such that the inequality holds, right? Or are you in fact asking whether there exists a $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, the inequality holds?

Comment: I am asking whether there exists a$ N$  such that for all$ n\geq N$, the inequality holds?

Comment: Um, is that a confirmation or are you asking what I am asking?